# What is the best practice to run 2 pipelines on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab-ci

What is the best practice to run 2 pipelines on the same project?

pipeline_1:

- build jars jobs and run tests jobs
- should be run each merge request.

pipeline_2:

- build jars jobs and run e2e tests jobs
- should be run every day.

Can I create 2 pipelines on the same project?

where one scheduled and second on each merge request and part of build jobs are common for both pipelines, but tests jobs are different.

Answer (score 1):

Each "stage" in the .gitlab-ci.yml file is considered a pipeline, so this should just be a matter of adding the correct scripting for each stage.

On `pipeline_2`, you could set it to a pipeline schedule and make it dependent on the success of `pipeline_1`. That's what I would do.

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html